# Testing a Angular Factory Service with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I had been trying to write a simple spec, but "couldn't load the module" is the error i get when i start Karma.I have a complete AngularJs REST application which has the has the same module name in all the Factory service .Module name is "app"..In one js file it doesn't require any modules as dependencies but in other files it required some in built angular js modules say for example 'ngRoute'..

So What i did was ,in karma.conf.js i included all the js files which had angular.module text in it...most of the js files had same module name "app" and some js files used inbuilt modules

Now coming to the Spec...When i try to include a module "app" in beforEach block and run the Test case...I got a error saying "module app cannot be loaded,it may require some dependencies as second argument".

SO i guessed it might require even the inbuilt dependency modules that were present in other js files,,so i passed those module names as second argument in my spec file..

```
beforeEach(function(){
  module('app',['ngRoute',......]);
});
```

Even that din't work out.the above beforEachBlock is just an Example  and have not used it..Just a question to understand..
.Below is the sample spec i used

**spec.js**

```
describe('Factory Service Testing', function(){
var familyService;
beforeEach(function(){
  module('app');
});

beforeEach(inject(function(familyService){
    familyService=familyService;
}));

it('Testing a Family', function(){
/*
 * 
 * some Code
 * 
 * */

});

  });
```

**FactoryService.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
    .factory('deepak', deepak);

    deepak.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$http', '$q', 'FamilyServices'];

}());
```

Am getting the below error

Chrome 50.0.2661 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load
 it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

**Karma.conf.js file**

```
 files: [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    'app/deep.js',
    'app/*.js',   -- >Path contains my Factory service 
    'tests/*.js'   --->Path contains the spec file
    ],
```

Am not Getting the module not found error if i simply mock the the modules in beforEEach block,,,but if i try to mock the Factory service then am getting module not found error

Comment: You need to specify your modules dependencies. I see you use ngRoute so add a `module('ngRoute')` before your `module('app')`.

You also need to `inject(function(_familyService_))` then assign `familyService = _familyService_` so that the service name and function argument don't conflict.

Comment: That was just an example..I dint actually try with..ngRoute is actually in the real code base...

The specs which i shared is the one am using for testing

Comment: Yes but if your factory is part of the `app` module, and `app` depends on `ngRoute`, then you need to test with the full environment aswell.

Comment: Cool...Am clear with module dependencies question.....I have Shared spec.js,karma.conf.js and FactoryService.js whch has a module that doesn't depend on any other module...because i have newly created it....But Still am getting module not defined error

Comment: Include you module file just after angular-mocks.js, files are read and executed from top to bottom and you may have retrieved your `app` module before it's actually declared. 

**ie:** if you use `angular.module('app').factory(...)` in deep.js

Comment: Yeah the module order defined in karma.conf.file does matter....That has fixed the Error of modules but now am getting  Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string